# ArrayList behaves very strangely

Tags: java, jdbc, arraylist

I am retrieving data from *XLS* sheet using *jdbc sql*. Below is my program.

Case 1:

```
Class.forName( "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" );
c = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:Excel Files", "", "" );
stmnt = c.createStatement();
String query = "select * from [Proficiency$];";
ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery( query );
baseColumnList = new ArrayList();
while( rs.next()) {
    //baseColumnList.add(rs.getString(1));
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    //System.out.println(baseColumnList);
}
```

output :

```
Aadmin
Badmin
Badminimage
batch
Cadmin
Dadmin
Eadmin
rulesengine
Fadmin
genadmin
Gadmin
Hdomain-EU
Padmin
IAA
```

Case 2:

```
Class.forName( "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" );
c = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:Excel Files", "", "" );
stmnt = c.createStatement();
String query = "select * from [Proficiency$];";
ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery( query );
baseColumnList = new ArrayList();
while( rs.next()) {
    baseColumnList.add(rs.getString(1));
    System.out.println(baseColumnList);
}
```

Output :

```
[Aadmin]
[Aadmin, Badmin]
[Aadmin, Badmin, Badminimage]
[Aadmin, Badmin, Badminimage, batch]
[Aadmin, Badmin, Badminimage, batch, Cadmin]
[Aadmin, Badmin, Badminimage, batch, Cadmin, Dadmin]
[Aadmin, Badmin, Badminimage, batch, Cadmin, Dadmin, Eadmin]
[Aadmin, Badmin, Badminimage, batch, Cadmin, Dadmin, Eadmin, rulesengine]
[Aadmin, Badmin, Badminimage, batch, Cadmin, Dadmin, Eadmin, rulesengine, Fadmin]
[Aadmin, Badmin, Badminimage, batch, Cadmin, Dadmin, Eadmin, rulesengine, Fadmin, genadmin]
[Aadmin, Badmin, Badminimage, batch, Cadmin, Dadmin, Eadmin, rulesengine, Fadmin, genadmin, Gadmin]
[Aadmin, Badmin, Badminimage, batch, Cadmin, Dadmin, Eadmin, rulesengine, Fadmin, genadmin, Gadmin, Hadmin-EU]
[Aadmin, Badmin, Badminimage, batch, Cadmin, Dadmin, Eadmin, rulesengine, Fadmin, genadmin, Gadmin, Hadmin-EU, Padmin]
[Aadmin, Badmin, Badminimage, batch, Cadmin, Dadmin, Eadmin, rulesengine, Fadmin, genadmin, Gadmin, Hadmin-EU, Padmin, IAA]
```

Please can anyone explain why arraylist is behaving strangly.

**Update : Expected result is first output.**

Comment: Can you explain what your expected result is? I cannot see the error, since it looks like the result that appears is expected from your code.

Comment: yes, what is the strangeness that you are mentioning, Case 1 : You just print the rs.getString(1). And in Case 2 you have added rs.getString(1) to the baseColumnList and print all elements in the arrayList in each iteration.

Comment: i need result as first output when printing from arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
System.out.println(baseColumnList);
```

prints the actual content<sup>1</sup> of the list. The result is not strange at all. The list get's bigger on each iteration.

---

To repeat the output of your first example:

```
while( rs.next()) {
  baseColumnList.add(rs.getString(1));
  System.out.println(baseColumnList.get(baseColumnList.size()-1));
}
```

But that's nonsense. The following snippet is more elegant:

```
while( rs.next()) {
  String columnValue = rs.getString(1);
  baseColumnList.add(columnValue);
  System.out.println(columnValue);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually `baseColumnList.toString()` is called.

Comment: how can i get result as first output using arraylist

Comment: Instead, use `System.out.println(baseColumnList.get(baseColumnList.size()-1));`

Comment: but i want to print it from ArrayList only.Not taking anothe string element and printing it.

Comment: Then use the *nonsense* version. Unfortunatley the `List` interface has no `last()` method. We have to use `size()` to calculate the index of the last list element. (And that is the one that has been added in the actual iteration)

Comment: @ Damodor : What is the point of getting the last element of ArrayList to print it when you already have it in hand? I mean why are you looking for Andreas_D's first approach when you already have the second elegant one? What is the exact use of it?

Answer (score 1):

Im not so sure what you think is 'strange'.
In the second case you are printing the entire baseColumnList for every result in your resultset.

```
System.out.println(baseColumnList);
```

As you can see it keeps adding the items to your baseColumnlist, so this is not strange at all, in fact it's what you expect to happen

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This seem expected from your code. Let me explain:

```
//this line adds a value to the list
baseColumnList.add(rs.getString(1));

//this line prints the whole list
System.out.println(baseColumnList);
```

- In the first line you add value to the list,
- In the second line you print the whole list.

In each iteration the list grows by one element and is printed after it. To prevent this, don't print the whole list, but some intermediate value, like:

```
//intermediate value
String temp= rs.getString(1);
//add it to the list
baseColumnList.add(temp);
//print only the value, and not the whole list
System.out.println(temp);
```

Comment: Another thing, what kind of output do you expect?

Comment: please check the question , i have updated the expected output

Comment: while( rs.next())
            {
                String temp= rs.getString(1);
                baseColumnList.add(temp);
                System.out.println(temp);
            }

Answer (score 0):

```
    Class.forName( "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" );

        c = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:Excel Files", "", "" );
        stmnt = c.createStatement();
        String query = "select * from [Proficiency$];";
        ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery( query );
        baseColumnList = new ArrayList();
        while( rs.next())
        {

            baseColumnList.add(rs.getString(1));
        }
       for(Object o: baseColumnList)
       {
         System.out.println((String)o);

       }
```